# How to create curved UIButton for iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uibutton, custom-controls

I want to create UIButtons which are curved. For demo look at this image.

[image: curved buttons]

I don't want to create the exact buttons, but they will have curve like this buttons. Is it possible to create such buttons in iOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton),
its a UIButton subclass for non-rectangular  shapes.

Comment: Good library. I'll run it tomorrow and will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: This library says that it will not respond to transparent part of the image but initially it responds to few click on transparent part. Once I click on part of the screen other than button and click on transparent part of the image then it does not respond. Do you know any fix? I don't want it to respond to transparent part.

Comment: ive used it in my project it works perfectly, see the complex shape demo in the Library for better understanding. Also are you using .jpg image, instead of .png..? because .jpg cannot be transparent afaik.

Comment: I ran complex button demo and I found that it too has bugs. I am attaching an image in my question showing what happens. So the bug is that if I run the demo and click on transparent part of the image then button actually responds to few first clicks. This no. of clicks are not the same each time I run the demo. Is there any way I can contact the owner of library?

Comment: Here is the link to the Author's [Blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/).